# Plug Cat5 cable into nic of one machine, brings other machine offline

Tags: networking

I have a really odd problem.  I have two machines, and I believe the nic is defective in one machine.

When I plug a cat 5 cable into it, it brings my other machine offline and only way to bring it online is to reboot.  If the cable stays in, it may not come back on reboot.

The other machine that causes the problem, seems to work fine, no signs of a bad network card.  I replaced the cable thinking it maybe a cable problem, same issue.  This worked fine before, and sometimes it works without a problem but then happens.  It doesn't happen everytime.

Comment: what are these machines connected to? what do they run?

Comment: One is Windows 8, one that "causes" the problem is Hackintosh.  Both are connected into an 8 port gigabit switch, nothing else seems to be problematic on the switch.

Comment: since its a hackintosh, could you rule out that its the OS by trying this with a livecd?

Comment: sounds like they have the same IP address.

Comment: so troubleshoot try a PCI or PCIe I suppose, NIC card

Comment: It happens when the machine is not in the OS, I can see the activity light blinking rapidly non-stop on the hackintosh.  I am pretty sure the nic is bad but it happens with both on-board nics and from the perspective of the hackintosh, it shows no problems.  It is not an IP overlap issue, they are both statically assigned.